# How do I build a XML file using Qt classes and functions and escape all non-Unicode characters?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, character-encoding, escaping

#### **The problem**

I am trying to create a set of functions that allows a user to create an XML and put it inside XML file.
The problem is, user can decide by himself encoding of the XML and encoding of the file.
So, I am interested in the situation when the user decided to create an ASCII XML and put inside ASCII file. The problem is, that he might want to put some Unicode characters inside ASCII XML and I would like to character escape every non-ASCII character.
Is there a way to do it without implementing own converter function?

#### **I tried...**

I already tried *QDomDocument* class and all related to it. But it only converts invalid XML characters: <,>,&... 
And if I put some Unicode characters, it will not escape them, despite encoding that I indicated inside XML declaration.

#### **Some code**

One of the examples how I am trying to do this

```
QString data("version=\"1.0\" encoding=ASCII");
QDomProcessingInstruction instr = m_doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", data);
m_doc.appendChild(instr);
QDomElement elem = m_doc.createElement(elemName.getQString());
QDomNode appendTo = m_current.isNull() ? m_doc : m_current;
appendTo.appendChild(elem);
m_current = elem;
QDomText text = m_doc.createTextNode(elemValue.getQString());
m_current.appendChild(text);
m_current = m_current.parentNode();
```

Also, were trying to do this with modern QXmlStreamWriter

```
QString output;
QXmlStreamWriter stream(&output);
stream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1250"));
stream.writeStartDocument();
stream.writeStartElement("bookmark");
stream.writeTextElement("title", "&ö");
stream.writeEndElement(); // bookmark
stream.writeEndDocument();
```

***Expected XML:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Message>
  <Label>&#xF9; &lt;> &amp;' </Label>
  <Name>&amp;&#xF6;</Name>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
</Message>
```

***Actual XML:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Message>
  <Label>ù &lt;> &amp;' </Label>
  <Name>&amp;ö</Name>
  <Text>Hello</Text>
</Message>
```

**P.S.** I also tried more specific encoding, like Windows-1260, Windows-1268, but they not converting all of them, only `ù` converted to `&#xf9;`, but `ö` stays `ö`. And even in some encoding, it is not converted at all.

Comment: Is ASCII mandatory? If not you can use utf-8 to save the file...

Comment: @Gasteizko yeah, customer requirement. I also proposed them utf-8, but apparently, they will read our XML through the program that only can read ASCII files. So, I need this working.

Comment: Are you actually using a QString with QXmlStreamWriter? Note that "When writing the XML to a QString, the codec information is ignored and the XML header will not include any encoding information, since all QStrings are UTF-16" (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#setCodec-1). With your code, I don't get the encoding in the processing instruction. I'd use QByteArray instead.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Tried that one, and apparently, it is not escaping anything, because, I tried to convert it back to QString and it gave me ????. And according to the debugger, _QByteArray_ also contains "?" instead proper escaped characters.

Comment: I found a way, see the answer...

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve is to use your own encode function.

```cpp
QString encodeEntities(QString sourceText)
{
    QString tempText(sourceText);
    int len = tempText.length();
    int i = 0;
    while( i<len )
    {
        if( tempText[i].unicode() > 128  ){
            QString replaceText = "&#x"+QString::number(tempText[i].unicode(),16)+";"; // HEX format
            tempText.replace(i,1,replaceText);
            len += replaceText.length()-1;
            i += replaceText.length();
        }else{
            QString replaceText = tempText[i];
            replaceText = replaceText.toHtmlEscaped(); // Warning! Read bottom note
            tempText.replace(i,1,replaceText);
            len += replaceText.length()-1;
            i += replaceText.length();
        }
    }
    return tempText;
}
```

And the to use the `QXmlStreamWriter` you need to do some hacks, see below:

```cpp
    QString output;
    QXmlStreamWriter stream(&output);
    stream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8"));
    stream.writeStartDocument();
    stream.writeStartElement("bookmark");       //Start bookmark
    {
        stream.writeStartElement("title");      // Start title
        stream.writeCharacters("");             // You need this to create a closed element, if not will create an open element
        output.append(encodeEntities("&ö"));    // Hack to not use the codec from QXmlStreamWriter
        stream.writeEndElement();               // End title
    }
    stream.writeEndElement();                   // End bookmark
    stream.writeEndDocument();
```

This works for me and outputs the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><bookmark><title>&amp;&#xf6;</title></bookmark>
```

> NOTE: `toHtmlEscaped()` converts a plain text string to an HTML string with HTML metacharacters <, >, &, and " replaced by HTML entities. [1]

[1] https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toHtmlEscaped

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Yes, I definitely can do that and I have converter function already implemented. But I asked if I can do this without own converter function: "_Is there a way to do it without implementing own converter function?_"
So, responsibility is on Qt functions.
I thought that maybe problem is here: `QString data("version=\"1.0\" encoding=?");`. **If exists encoding** that has 8-bit empty, the conversion is handled by Qt functions. For, example `ISO-8859-5` will escape ö and ù, but will not escape г, ї or є.